# Find TOC in shapes (i.e. textboxes)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a macro that counts and locates TOCs within the document (a routine check rather than for a specific file).

TOCs situated in the document's 'body' are easily accessible (via VBA).
Word also lets users place TOC objects inside of shapes (textboxes), but these do not seem to be accessible via code. Granted, it is not that common to have TOCs placed within shapes, but if it is possible - it should be taken into account.

This makes counting and detecting them unreliable.

The only way I know and intuitively thought of was this:

```
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
       iCount = iCount + shp.TextFrame.TextRange.<TableOfContents.Count>    <<< no access to TableOfContents
    Next shp
```

What code do I need in order to find those TOCs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TablesOfContents` collection is only available on a `Document` object. A TOC in the main body of the document will pick up items in textboxes; a TOC in a textbox will pick up items in the main body of the document. (At least, since Word 2010; there was a time when TOCs in text boxes were not "visible" to a TOC field in the main document body.)

However, the VBA property `Document.TablesOfContents` does not pick up TOCs in text boxes, only in the main body.

So, it's not possible to *directly* query the number of TOCs in a text box (or AutoShape - a drawing object). That said...

TOCs are managed in the background by Word using the `TOC` field code. So it is possible to ascertain the number of TOC fields in a given `Range`. For example:

```
Sub GetAllToc()
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim tbRange As Range
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim fld As Word.Field

    Debug.Print "TOCs in main Document body: " & ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Count

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Or shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            Set tbRange = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            For Each fld In tbRange.Fields
                If fld.Type = wdFieldTOC Then
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next shp
    Debug.Print "TOCs in text boxes: " & iCount
End Sub
```